# Trouble deploying solidity smart contract with "invalid or unexpected token" error

Tags: deployment, syntax-error, solidity, smartcontracts

Trying to replicate a smart contract in a testing environment for practice. When I go to deploy the contract, I am getting "SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token".  I've had to troubleshoot a few other problems, but can't seem to get past this one.  Can anyone help?

**2_deploy_contract.js**

```
var Etheremura = artifacts.require("Etheremura");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Etheremura, 0000000000000000000000000D86C54925E12a52a5929c167f20B989F499b3CB7), 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005f);
};
```

```
C:\Users\Rexdog979\eth>truffle migrate

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
√ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.



Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'development'
> Network id:      5777
> Block gas limit: 6721975 (0x6691b7)


2_deploy_contracts.js
=====================

C:\Users\Rexdog979\eth\migrations\2_deploy_contracts.js:4
  deployer.deploy(Etheremura, 0000000000000000000000000D86C54925E12a52a5929c167f20B989F499b3CB7), 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005f);
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (node:vm:99:7)
    at Object.createScript (node:vm:260:10)
    at Object.file (C:\Users\Rexdog979\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\require\require.js:93:1)
    at Migration._load (C:\Users\Rexdog979\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\Migration.js:49:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Migration.run (C:\Users\Rexdog979\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\Migration.js:212:1)
    at Object.runMigrations (C:\Users\Rexdog979\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\index.js:150:1)
    at Object.runFrom (C:\Users\Rexdog979\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\index.js:110:1)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\Rexdog979\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\index.js:87:1)
    at runMigrations (C:\Users\Rexdog979\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\commands\migrate.js:258:1)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\Rexdog979\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\commands\migrate.js:223:1)
    at Command.run (C:\Users\Rexdog979\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\command.js:147:1)
Truffle v5.3.6 (core: 5.3.6)
Node v16.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a redundant closing brace `)` after the second argument in the `deployer.deploy()` function.

It also seems that you're trying to pass an address and an unsigned integer as ABI-encoded values. However, the Truffle `deploy()` function accepts JS scalars - not the ABI encoded values.

So you could do something like this:

```
deployer.deploy(
    Etheremura,
    '0xD86C54925E12a52a5929c167f20B989F499b3CB7', // assuming it's an address
    95 // assuming it's an integer, 5f hex == 95 decimal
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the deploy function `deployer.deploy(Etheremura, 0000000000000000000000000D86C54925E12a52a5929c167f20B989F499b3CB7), 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005f);` you have a unnecessary closing bracket after your address.

Also provide your address like `"0xD86C54925E12a52a5929c167f20B989F499b3CB7"` and value in the form of an integer. Also make sure that the address you are providing is a valid Ethereum address.